# Notepad++ Reindent file keyboard shortcut not working

Tags: notepad++, keyboard-shortcuts, text-alignment, auto-indent, text-indent

[image]

i have created a new shortcut in Notepad++ and i can see that as `Ctrl+Alt+Shift+F` but when i try to use that shortcut code it is not working and so i have to click manually `plugins->indentByFold->ReindentFile`  Is there any solution to work this short cut..?

i Can use shortcut for net-beans that is `CTRL + A` then `ALT + SHIFT + F` by using this i can make the code in good format like tree/steps it will look good and easy to understand the program as well. I am looking for same kind of shortcut for net-beans is there any short there or can i create a shortcut how can i approach it.?

Please Suggest Edit if my question not reached the standards.

Comment: There is no good edit to suggest here. You're requesting help on 3rd party software. This has nothing to do with coding and therefor simply doesn't fit on Stack Overflow at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> is already defined in Npp, its meaning is: `unfold current bloc` (Not sure of the translation, I haven't an english version of Npp)

You have to choose another shortcut that doesn't exists in actual list of shortcuts.